# Снять "константу" с переменной swift

Tags: swift, const

Стало интересно, как можно убрать метку "константа" с переменной в языке **Swift**. Например, в **С++** это выглядит так: 

**UPDATE: Более подходящий пример на С++**

```
void func2(int *ptrA) {
}

void func3(int &a) {
}

void func1(const int a) {
// Тут снимается "const" с переменной при помощи const_cast
// Возможно ли так же снять let с переменной в swift?
    func2(const_cast<int*>(&a) ); 
// Тут тоже снимаем const
    func3( *(const_cast<int*>(&a)) );   
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    func1(a);
}
```

А как выглядит эта строчка на Swift? И возможно ли такое сделать? Вопрос из любопытства

Comment: Для начала, что вы называете константой в Swift? Если вы про ключевое слово 'let', то это не константа.

Comment: @Olter да, про "let". Только отчего она не константа? В официальном учебнике уверяют, что именно она. При попытке изменить появляется типичная ошибка `cannot assign to value: 'varName' is a 'let' constant`

Comment: Строго говоря let не является константой, т.к let можно определить в рантайме (для классической константы такое не возможно, она определяется на этапе ЕМНИП предкомпиляции). Определение в рантайме часто используется при работе с монадами (optional binding, optional chaining) в записях вида `if let name = textfield.text { print(name) }`. Классическая константа в swift задается через `static let`, если я ничего не путаю.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы в коде на c++ присваиваете в nonConstVar не само значение константы, а указатель на нее?

Comment: @Olter Про указатель: нет, если присмотритесь, то перед `const_cast` вы можете заметить, что стоит операция разыменования, благодаря ей вытаскиваю всё-таки значение. А касательно let: даже не знал о такой возможности.

Comment: Я тогда не очень понимаю смысл фразы "убрать метку константа". Можете написать `var nonConst = nonConst`  это присвоит значение константы (Int в Swift это структура и передается по значению) и пользоваться дальше var-ом. Что сделать-то хотите?

Comment: @Olter вы правы, пример был ужасен, уже обновил. Давайте приведу ситуацию, так будет легче: у меня идёт спуск вызовов функций (т.е. одна вызывает другую, другая третью и т.д.). Во всех них одинаковые аргументы. Вот только в некоторых используются сквозные, в некоторых - обычные. Передать обычный параметр в другую в качестве сквозного не могу, т.к. он автоматически становится константным. Что бы не производить копирование (как с Int случаем), мне хотелось бы снять const. Это иллюстрируют вызовы **func2** и **func3**. Есть ли возможность так же сделать на Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из вашего вопроса, комментариев и собственных догадок, попробую ответить.

Для "сквозных" параметров существует атрибут `inout`:

```
func squareValueTypeInt(number: inout Int) {
    number *= number
}
var someNumber = 10
print(someNumber) // -> 10
squareValueTypeInt(number: &someNumber)
print(someNumber) // -> 100
```

`let` для того и является иммутабельным чтобы его не меняли, даже `UnsafePinters` и подобные Вам в этом вопросе не друзья. Если нужно изменить значение `let` - что-то спроектировано неправильно.

Не знаком с С++, но чую, что приведенный пример - плохая практика даже для С++. А Swift проектировался чтобы не "стрелять себе в ногу".

Comment: Вы правы, это плохая практика, но порой выручает. "let для того и является иммутабельным чтобы его не меняли" - благодарю, это и есть ответ на мой вопрос